# How to resize a path without resizing the text on it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path, resize

I made an ellipse path and used the "type on a path tool" tool to make a rounded text effect, but when I'm resizing the path, the font resizes too, according to the path aspect ratio.

Is there any way to resize a path while maintaining the font size?

Answer (score 4):

An apparently not so known feature of Adobe Illustrator is that the path that you typed on still remains a separate object, albeit grouped under the text object. You can select just the path with any of the 2 white arrow tools allows you to select the sub object.

[image]

After you have selected the sub object you can manipulate it just as it was just the path and not touch the text. The text will re flow in this case. You could also color the line.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you "Type on the path tool", you basically asking illustrator that "What ever happen keep this bulk of text i am about to create all the way rounded". Therefore illustrator prioritise the text in the circle path, not the circle of the text. (As proof, If you check the layers you will see that both the text and the path form one layer. Now select the layer and try to change its background color, you will see that the text color changes instead). So if you still want to control the round path outside the text, then you will have to create another round path around your text and you will be able to resize it without touching the text using only the resize tool and the stroke. Make sure that the second Circle path background is set to Transparent and stays on top of the rounded text layer.

Answer (score 0):

joojaa's solution didn't work for me, so another solution I found is to save the text as a paragraph style, then when you resize your path you can just re-apply the paragraph style.